# Async call results to Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded in React & Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I have an app built with React, Redux that pulls data from a RESTful service sitting in my local. I tested the implementation with dummy data and works fine. However, when I hook up the async service the calls result in havoc with the below error:
[image]

Here is the code

```
reducer.js

import {
  LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
  LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
  LOAD_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  LOAD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  LOAD_PRODUCT_FAIL,
} from './actions';

export const productData = (state = { loader: {}, products: [] }, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST: {
      return { loader: true, products: [] };
    }
    case LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS: {
      return { loader: false, products: payload };
    }
    case LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL: {
      return { loader: false, error: payload };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

thunk.js

import axios from 'axios';
import { mockData } from '../MockData';
import {
  loadAllProductFailed,
  loadAllProductRequest,
  loadAllProductSuccess,
  LOAD_PRODUCT_FAIL,
  LOAD_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  LOAD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
} from './actions';

export const loadInitialProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(loadAllProductRequest());
    //this is where the issues is
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/v1/product/all');
    const payload = await response.data;
    console.log(payload);
    dispatch(loadAllProductSuccess(payload));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(
      loadAllProductFailed(
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message
      )
    );
  }
};

export const loadProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: LOAD_PRODUCT_REQUEST });
    //do a axios api call for product api
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
      payload: mockData.find(({ productId }) => productId == id),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_PRODUCT_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST = 'LOAD_PRODUCTS_REQUEST';
export const loadAllProductRequest = () => ({
  type: LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
});

export const LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = 'LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS';
export const loadAllProductSuccess = (payload) => ({
  type: LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: payload,
});

export const LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL = 'LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL';
export const loadAllProductFailed = (error) => ({
  type: LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
  payload: error,
});

export const LOAD_PRODUCT_REQUEST = 'LOAD_PRODUCT_REQUEST';
export const loadProductRequest = () => ({
  type: LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
});

export const LOAD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS = 'LOAD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS';
export const loadProductSuccess = (payload) => ({
  type: LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
  payload: payload,
});

export const LOAD_PRODUCT_FAIL = 'LOAD_PRODUCT_FAIL';
export const loadProductFailed = (error) => ({
  type: LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
  payload: error,
});

Home.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { conwayAPI } from '../ConwayAPI';
import { Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Product from './Product';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import _ from 'lodash';
import { loadInitialProducts } from '../app/thunk';

const Home = () => {
  //local state maintained only for this component
  const [filterProducts, setFilterProducts] = useState([]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productData);
  const { loader, error, products } = productList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadInitialProducts());
  }, [dispatch, products]);

  const doSearch = (text) => {
    _.isEmpty(text)
      ? setFilterProducts(products)
      : setFilterProducts(
          filterProducts.filter((product) =>
            product.productName.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
          )
        );
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row md={7} lg={5} className='justify-content-md-center'>
        {filterProducts.length &&
          filterProducts.map((datam, key) => {
            return (
              <Col key={key}>
                <Product product={datam} key={key} />
              </Col>
            );
          })}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

When I click on a Nav panel the Home.js gets called and the error starts. What can I do differently to eliminate this error?

Comment: Why is `products` a dependency of your effect? It'll run the effect after mount so products are being fetched, then products are set so it'll run the effect again. Also all your actions seem to create a LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL action type.

Comment: @HMR `products ` was the issue! Thanks for pointing that out. 
I am still working on this, the actions are not completed yet.